# Does $abc$ preclude very smooth solutions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, abc-conjecture

Recall the $abc$-conjecture, which asserts that for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a positive number $C(\epsilon)$ such that for any coprime integers $a,b,c$ with $a + b = c$ and $\max\{|a|, |b|, |c|\} = |c|$ we have

$$\displaystyle |c| < C(\epsilon) \text{rad}(abc)^{1 + \epsilon}.$$

Here

$$\text{rad}(n) = \prod_{p | n} p,$$

where by convention all primes involved in the product are positive (even though $n$ may not be).

The best known (uncontroversial) result towards the $abc$-conjecture is due to Stewart and Yu, which gives the bound

$$\displaystyle |c| < \exp \left(C(\epsilon)\text{rad}(abc)^{1/3 + \epsilon} \right).$$

However, this is a corollary of their more refined results, which actually depends on the largest prime factor of $abc$. To quote their paper:

**"An examination of our proof reveals that the impediment to a further refinement
of Theorem 1 is not the dependence on the number of terms in the estimates for
linear forms in logarithms but instead is the dependence on the parameter p in the
p-adic estimates. This fact is highlighted by our next result which shows that if the
greatest prime factor of one of x, y and z is small relative to G then the estimate
for z from Theorem 1 can be improved."**

This motivates the following question: can the $abc$-conjecture be strengthened to only depend on the largest prime factor of $abc$? In other words, is it possible for there to be infinitely many triples of co-prime integers $a,b,c$ such that $a + b = c$ and each $a,b,c$ is very smooth compared to $\max\{|a|, |b|, |c|\}$?

Comment: I edited the first sentence by placing the quantifiers in an order that seemed more accurate to me. Apologies if I introduced an error.

Comment: (I now see KConrad had a similar comment on your question from 10 years ago: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59906/a-question-related-to-the-abc-conjecture.)

Comment: Incidentally regarding the *actual content* of your question, I'm afraid I don't understand it: what does it mean for "each $a,b,c$" to be "very smooth compared to $\max\{|a|,|b|,|c|\}$"?

Comment: Perhaps what is meant is to get a lower exponent for rad(abc) at the cost of some additional factor involving the largest prime \(P^+(abc)\)? Incidentally, Lagarias and Soundararajan have studied the analogue of this conjecture with \(P^+\) instead of rad, see https://jtnb.centre-mersenne.org/item/10.5802/jtnb.757.pdf

Comment: @Sary I think the paper your mentioned seems to be what I am looking for. If you could write that as an answer then I will accept it.

Comment: @‍KConrad's [comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/59906/a-question-related-to-the-abc-conjecture.#comment150427_59906) [mentioned](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410272/does-abc-preclude-very-smooth-solutions#comment1052672_410272) by @SamHopkins.

Comment: @Sary's [reference](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/410272/does-abc-preclude-very-smooth-solutions#comment1052712_410272):  [Smooth solutions to the $abc$ equation: the $xyz$ Conjecture](https://doi.org/10.5802/jtnb.757).